# Connect Meteor.js app via DDP.loginWithPassword, Meteor.user() is undefined

Tags: meteor

I have 2 Meteor apps. A server app and a client app. I log on the server with this function:

Client:

```
 DDP.loginWithPassword(ddp.getConnection(), {email: 'me@me.com'}, 'myPasswort', function (error, result) {
       if (error)
         return alert(error);
       Meteor.call('showLogin');
     });
```

On the server app I have the method that shows me that I'm logged in.

```
Meteor.methods({
showLogin: function() { 
    console.log(Meteor.user());
  }
});
```

As far as everything works, but on the client app `Meteor.user()` is undefined?

Why, and how do I solve the problem?

Comment: If you use Angular 2, did you add `@InjectUser('user')` for your component ?

Comment: I use angular 1, is there a synonym?

Comment: I don't know, but in their [tutorial](http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular1/user-accounts-authentication-and-permissions) they just `import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';` and it do the work.

Comment: Instead of calling `Meteor.call('showLogin');`, if you call directly `Meteor.user()` or `Meteor.userId()` do you have something that it's not undefined ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the below line for Accounts and users population and then try getting the userId.

```
Accounts.connection = Meteor.remoteConnection;
```

Meteor.userId works instead of Meteor.user(). This is because in DDP-login package, once loggedin the callback sets only the userID and not the user() function.

**ddp-login.js**
 connection.setUserId(result.id);